# SQLite update returns effected row count but data is not updated

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I have a method which updates a single row in a table as below. Every now an then some rows will return a row count of 1 from the update method, but the value is not updated. Once that happens for a row it will always behave the same way. Other rows will be update just fine.

```
public void SetImageStatusToCompleted(String imageId)
   {
       String where = "id=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(imageId)};
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("status", 0);
        int success;
        try 
        {  
            db.beginTransaction();
            success = db.update("images", args, where, whereArgs);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }
```

I just cant figure it out. There is never any exception and as I indicated the value of success is always 1 indicating 1 row has been update.

Thanks!

Comment: remember after the update the value is not returned hence you can't see the reflection on UI but it has been successfully inserted

Comment: @MDMalik - I know it is not updated because at a later time I query the table and the status has not changed for the given image record.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this codes? it's working for me and more easy to use.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("Row", "value");
db.update("DBName", values, Condition or query ex: "Number='"+ mobile +"'",null);
```

Comment: I have tried this syntax and it still exhibits the same behavior. Most of the time things are fine but every now and then a row will become un-updatable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. In my table create statement I had missed the AUTOINCREMENT in the definition of the _id field. I do not know exactly how a value was returned from the select cursor for the _id field, but it did not correspond to the row I was intending to update.

Adding in the AUTOINCREMENT corrected the problem.

Thanks!